# Connecting to SQL Azure from a Java application

Tags: sql-server, azure, jdbc, connection-string, azure-sql-database

I have a Java Application that connects to an SQL server database via JDBC driver and everything works fine.
I have lately migrated my Database to the Azure SQL server and so the Java application.
Of course, I modifided the connction string to point at this new adress, but I keep getting this next error:

Connection TCP/IP of the HTTP xxxxxxx.database.windows.net, port 1433: ERROR : connection time out. verify connexion properties, make sure an instance of SQL server is running and accepts TCP/IP connections and verify that Firewall is not blocking TCP connexion.

here is my connection sring:

jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=xxxxxxx;user=xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx;password=xxxxxxx;encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;

What is missing right there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you allowed access to the database server from that particular IP address?

If not, go to the management portal

- select the database
- on the bottom right, select the server
- go to the configure tab
- enter the ip address (or range of them)

Comment: You can now specify database-specific IP ranges as well.